FPGA Cyclone V GX Fails at Low Temperatures (-40C)
I am using an Altera Cyclone V FPGA (5CGXFC7D6F27I7N) on a custom carrier board to convert DisplayPort video (input) to BT.656 video data (output). The output video data is then sent to an encoder, which produces analog video (NTSC).
The system works perfectly at room temperature, but when tested in an environmental chamber at temperatures of -20°C and below, the FPGA fails to output video.
Setup:
A COM Express (COMe) module on the carrier board provides two DisplayPort outputs:
One goes to a monitor (works fine, even at cold temperatures).
The other goes to the FPGA (fails at cold temperatures).
FPGA processes DisplayPort video and outputs BT.656 video data to an encoder.
Troubleshooting Done:
Voltage Rails and Clocks: All confirmed functional at cold temperatures.
Components: All hardware, including the FPGA, is industrial-temperature-rated.
Rework: FPGAs have been re-balled, and new FPGAs have been tested.
Signal Tapping:
At room temperature, I see proper AUX and HPD activity.
At cold temperatures, AUX and HPD signals are not triggered at boot up.
Forcing HPD: I tried forcing the FPGA’s HPD signal to always indicate "presence" to the COMe module, but this did not resolve the issue.
Hypothesis:
I suspect that the FPGA is not communicating with the COMe module at low temperatures, causing the COMe to ignore it.
Questions:
Any tips on whether I should focus on the FPGA or on the COMe.
Edit:
I had an observation regarding the Aux lines. At power on the AUX lines behave a expected. When the CPU boots up, there is a chirp about 3-6 seconds on the AUX line. When this chirp occurs, the system works as expected. When it doesn't chirp, they system fails.

Have you checked the device meets timing down to -40*C with TimeQuest?

Are your reference clocks still in range?

@TomCarpenter I have not checked TimeQuest, I need to get more knowledge on how to use the software tool.

@SimonRichter , I have only checked a couple of other clocks that go into the FPGA and they seem to be working fine. I think the DisplayPort clock is handled by the COMe. I'll look into it again.

After further testing I found our issue and a workaround. It seems that at cold temperatures the DisplayPort IP (intellectual property core) that we are using on the FPGA is not setting the Hot Plug Detect on time or at all, which causes the COMe (or the CPU on the COMe) to not detect the FPGA on time. For some reason, we are still researching, the COMe only detects monitors (FPGA acts as one) at boot up, so if it misses it, it will never activate the handshake. We removed the HPD signal from the DisplayPort IP and setting high at all times, or as soon as it gets power (as mentioned on the original post). However when we were first trying this, we were not removing the HPD signal from the IP and we were still messing the timing up.  Now that we fixed our FPGA logic we have been able to get it to work. We still are not understanding why the IP is having issues at cold.

Note that FPGAs like this one, as is the case for all Si digital devices, run faster (higher slew rates; lower delays) at lower temperatures.
